# Complex sql query - can't figure it out

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

- Table `tickets` {id, subject, appt_id}  //appt_id is empty 50% of the time
- Table `ticket_notes` {id, message, tickets_id}    //some
  tickets will not have notes and some tickets will have many
- Table `appt` {id, fname, lname, hash}    //some hash fields will be empty

I need to form the join so that I have all tickets with all their notes. In addition, if the ticket has an appt_id and if the corresponding row in the appt table has a hash, we need to display fname and lname from the APPT table at the top of the messages (that are aggregated for each ticket). I have the join between tickets and notes working fine (see below), but the additional issue of adding in the appt table just came up and I am not sure how to approach the conditional issue of not having appt_id in all tickets and not having hash in all appt rows.

```
SELECT tickets.id as id, tickets.subject as subject, 
    group_concat(n.message SEPARATOR '<br><br>') as messages  
    FROM tickets LEFT JOIN tickets_notes n ON n.`ticket_id` = tickets.`id` 
    GROUP BY tickets.id;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that not more than one record in `appt` will correspond to a given `ticket`, you can just add one more `LEFT JOIN`:

```
SELECT 
    t.id, 
    t.subject,
    a.lname,
    a.fname,
    group_concat(n.message SEPARATOR '<br><br>') as messages  
FROM tickets t
LEFT JOIN tickets_notes n ON n.`ticket_id` = t.`id` 
LEFT JOIN appt a ON a.id = t.appt_id AND a.hash IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY 
    t.id,
    t.subject,
    a.lname,
    a.fname
```

The join condition on `appt` matches `ticket(appt_id)` on `appt(id)`; there is an additional condition that `appt(hash)` should not be `null`.

Side notes:

- it is a good practice to list *all* non-aggregated columns in the `GROUP BY` clause (starting MySQL 5.7, this is mandatory by default - most other RDBMS work the same way)
- there is no need to alias columns like `t.id as id`: the original column name is used by default (you need alias when you want to assign a *different* name)
- I modified the query to use table aliases consistently

Comment: Much easier than I thought. Thanks!  Just for my knowledge, why would i want to put all non-aggregated columns in group by. I am not grouping by those other columns. I am grouping by id.

Comment: @MarkC.: see [MySQL Handling of `GROUP BY`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-handling.html) for more details on this.

Answer (score 1):

As I understand the requirement:

> we need to display fname and lname from the APPT table at the top of
>   the messages (that are aggregated for each ticket)

you can do it with [`CONCAT_WS()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat-ws) after you join the table `appt` also:

```
SELECT t.id, t.subject, 
  CONCAT_WS(
    '<br><br>', 
    CASE WHEN MAX(a.hash) IS NOT NULL THEN MAX(CONCAT(a.fname, ' ', a.lname)) END, 
    GROUP_CONCAT(n.message SEPARATOR '<br><br>')
  ) messages  
FROM tickets t 
LEFT JOIN tickets_notes n ON n.ticket_id = t.id 
LEFT JOIN appt a ON a.id = t.appt_id
GROUP BY t.id, t.subject;
```

Comment: Nice! I ended up doing the formatting and stuff with php code, but your answer is perfect for doing it through pure sql! (I apologize, but I already accepted the first answer because it got me over my major hurdle.)

Comment: So you accepted an answer that does not meet the requirement you set in your question?